# Sum of double in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sum, double

Am trying to make a sum of an array which has double. However I am getting wrong answer.

```
var d1 = new double[] { 26392.23, 35192.23, -26392.23, -35192.23 };
var d2 = d1.Sum(x => x);
```

output: 7.27595761418343E-12

**Expected Output: 0**

Comment: Because of `double` representation in memory

Comment: This is just how floating point arithmetic works.  Not every number can be represented with unlimited precision, so there are small errors when performing floating point maths.

Comment: `var d2 = d1.Sum(x => (decimal)x);`?

Comment: `var d2 = d1.Sum(x => (float)x);` should work too

Comment: @SᴇM it returns 0.00. Still expected is 0